# set a text if GetDate() is equal to a specific date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to show a specific text in a stored procedure if the date is dec 24'th. How can I check if the current date is dec 24'th and then set a specific text and otherwise the text should be blank.

Comment: This is a simple `CASE`, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 AND DAY(GETDATE()) = 24 
    THEN 'Merry Christmas!' 
    ELSE '' 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dateString nvarchar(50) = '2018-12-20';
declare @text nvarchar(50);
If Convert(Date, GetDate()) = Convert(Date, dateString)
   set @text = "This is it"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(datepart(MONTH,GETDATE())=12 AND  datepart(DAY,GETDATE())=24)
         SELECT 'it is dec 24th'
    else
         SELECT ' '
```

--- you can use datename() instead of datepart() to get month as text 12>>december

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 and above, below is a shorter and efficient script:

```
SELECT IIF(MONTH(GETDATE()) = 12 AND DAY(GETDATE()) = 24, 'Your Text', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**`FORMAT()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function, available in SQL 2012 and newer:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM-dd') = '12-24'
            THEN 'ALMOST XMAS'
            ELSE ''
            END AS TEXT
```

Or combined with [**`IIF()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql):

```
SELECT IIF(FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MM-dd') = '12-24', 'ALMOST XMAS', '') AS TEXT
```